# z-index:20 appears under the z-index:10 even if its z index bigger

Tags: jquery, css, z-index

i am trying to make a lightbulb. here is codes [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jm4pczeb/)

HTML

```
<input class="button" type="button">
<div id="black" style="display: none; position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; left: 0; top: 0; background: rgba(51,51,51,0.7); z-index: 10;"></div>

<div id="add" style="z-index: 20; display:none; border: 2px solid;">
    <input type="text" >
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    $('#add').show();
    $('#black').show();
})
```

in my mind when i hit `.button` , `#add` must be appear on top of `#black` because of its z-index(20) bigger than `#black` (10). but it appears under the `#black`. thanks for helping.

Comment: z-index only applies to positioned elements. your #add element is not positioned, therefore z-index is ignored and the default `0` index applies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the `z-index` property [only applies to positioned elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#layers).

The default value for the `position` property is `static`. If you added `position: relative` to that element, it would work as expected.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/tr54s0kr/)